# installation of OMD

Tags: centos6, epel

I am trying to install OMD in my CentOS 6.6 linux machine using this link [https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_install_with_omd.html.][1] Initially I installed epel repoistory and then when in tried installing OMD it says the following.

```
  [root@ctg-alpha-mon1 /]#  yum install --nogpgcheck omd-0.42-0.42-  

       centos55.14.x86_64.rpm
       Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, downloadonly, fastestmirror,  kabi, presto, refresh-packagekit, security, tmprepo,
          : verify, versionlock
Loading support for CentOS kernel ABI
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirrors.centarra.com
* epel: lug.mtu.edu
* extras: mirrors.centarra.com
* updates: mirrors.centarra.com
No package omd-0.42-0.42-centos55.14.x86_64.rpm available.
 Error: Nothing to do
```

I tried **'yum search omd*** ' or '**yum search omd-**' but still it says no package available. 
How do I install omd? I am pretty new to this.
Will omd package be available in the linux for us to install or should I get it from somewhere and then install it?
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OMD package is not available on a yum repository, except for subscribers. 
OMD package has to be downloaded from their site or lookup the community version. Have a look at http://omdistro.org/ and https://labs.consol.de/de/nagios/omd-repository/